# Spring Form Submit to Delete a Collection Item

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, controllers

I have a page that has a form backing object that contains a collections property that I loop through on the page. I want to give the user the option of deleting an item of the collection by clicking on a remove button.  However I don't know which remove button was pressed in the controller since each item in the collection has a remove button.  Basically I need to know which remove button was pressed so I know what question id should be deleted.  What is the best way to go about this?  Please see my page below:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/taglibs.jsp" %> 

<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="surveyInfo" > 

<table id="glossarysearchtable-full" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">            
            <tr align="left">
                <td class="searchResultTitle" colspan="2">
                    Schedule Number ${surveyInfo.surveyNumSch}                      
                    <input type="submit" class="small-short inner2" value="Save" alt="Save" title="Save"    />
                    <input type="button" class="small-short inner2" value="Print" alt="Print" title="Print" />
                    <input type="button" class="small-short inner2" value="Remove" alt="Remove" title="Remove"  /> 
                    <sf:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id" cssClass="inputbox-survey" maxlength="100" size="100" />   
                    <sf:input type="hidden" path="surveyTitle" id="surveyTitle" cssClass="inputbox-survey" maxlength="100" size="100" />
                    <sf:input type="hidden" path="surveyName" id="surveyName" cssClass="inputbox-survey" maxlength="100" size="100" /> 
            </tr>                                 

            <c:forEach items="${surveyInfo.allSurveyQuestions}" var="surveyQuestion" varStatus="status"> 

                    <tr align="left">
                        <td class="searchResultTitle" colspan="2">
                            Question ${status.count}  <input type="submit" class="small-short inner2" value="Remove${status.count}" alt="Remove" title="Remove" />
                            <sf:input type="hidden" path="allSurveyQuestions[${status.index}].questionId" id="questionId${status.count}" cssClass="inputbox-survey" maxlength="100" size="100" />
                            <sf:input type="hidden" path="allSurveyQuestions[${status.index}].id" id="id${status.count}" cssClass="inputbox-survey" maxlength="100" size="100" />
                      </td>

                    </tr>     

                    <tr class="altrow" align="left">
                        <td height="20">Text:</td>
                        <td><sf:input path="allSurveyQuestions[${status.index}].questionText" id="questionText${status.count}" cssClass="inputbox-survey" maxlength="100" size="100" /></td>
                    </tr> 

            </c:forEach> 
</table>    
</sf:form>
```

Comment: Have you thought of using jQuery Ajax to remove the clicked item? If you go this route, you can use the id of the element clicked, and send that id to the backend and remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved my issue, what I did was created a property called isDeleted in my domain object which is also my form backing object and created a bound checkbox for each record on the page.  If the user clicks on the checkbox or checkboxes and clicks saves, the controller checks the value of the checkbox and populates 2 different collections one for toBeSaved and another for toBeDeleted.  Unchecked records gets saved and checked records get deleted from the database.

I saw lots of options on the web to do this via the jquery route, but I am still learning jquery and preferred to do it server side.